# dscInfo dictionary - cups printing

Tags: linux, printing, cups

In my `.ppd` file, i see the following text:

```
*% If the dscInfo dictionary is not set using the printer driver, the
*% userlogin and job name are set to "CUPS User" and "CUPS Application"
*% respectively. If the dscinfo dictionary is set, document name and
*% user name are set as per the CUPS login name and Document name.
*% The default print mode is Normal.
```

My question is now, how and where do I set this dscInfo dictionary, so that I see the document name and user name.